# Linq Nested Query with Left Join and Inner Joins

Tags: sql, linq

Hi I have this query in SQL which I would like to convert to Linq (Entities), I am a beginner in this and I wonder how to:

```
        select k.ID from dbo.Cases k
        left join 
            (
                select c.ID, r.RelatedCaseID from dbo.Cases c 
                    inner join
                        (
                            select r.RelatedCaseID, r.CaseID from   dbo.RelatedCases r where r.CaseID = 368
                        ) r
                    on c.ID = r.RelatedCaseID
            ) c
        on k.ID = c.ID

        where k.ID <> 368 and c.RelatedCaseID is null
```

I would like to return this a function of return type of: IEnumerable object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these blog posts can help you out:

[Converting SQL to Linq](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/tags/converting+sql+to+linq/)